# Serve static html files omitting the .html extension in the url

Tags: spring-boot

When serving static html/css/js resources from `src/main/resources/static`, is there a way to have some form of url abstraction?

Precisely, I would like to remove the `.html` ending from the urls.

Comment: you mean from `http://localhost/index.html` to `http://localhost/index`?

Comment: yes for example

Comment: for me this works out of the box. I am using static html files with thymeleaf and dont have .html suffix in the url.

Comment: With plain html files the suffix is necessary since it seems to be a direct one-to-one mapping.

Comment: Ever figure this out using the basic `/static` directory?

Comment: No, sorry I did not...

Comment: @yglodt did you found any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return html static file without extension is the same as return view name from any of templates engines (jsp, theamleaf, freemarker), the thing here you do not need to run any templates processing on view file, you just return it as it is.

Add code below to your Spring configuration:

```java
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("pages/");
    internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return internalResourceViewResolver;
}
```

Be careful `/pages` folder should be inside your `ResourceLocation`
, that means `ResourceLocation + "/pages/" + pageName.html` in browser should give you desired file (if you already configured servicing of static files it will not be a problem for you to find your ResourceLocation, check method `addResourceHandlers` in your WebMvcConfigurer)

Now at your WebMvcConfigurer you can add:

```java
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    registry.addViewController("/admin").setViewName("admin");
    registry.addViewController("/contact").setViewName("contact");
    registry.addViewController("/error").setViewName("index");
}
```

or just use it, as you would use it in usual view resolver within MVC controller

```java
@GetMapping("/")
public String greeting() {
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A request mapping that ignores all URLs that have a  file extension and adds `.html` to URLs with no file extension.

```
@Controller
...

 @RequestMapping("/{page:^(?!.*[.].*$).*$}")
 public String requestOther(@PathVariable("page") String page) {
  return "/"+page+".html";
 }

...
```

Change the `"/"` to a sub directory if needed e.g. `"/pages/"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom resource resolver to add the `.html` suffix to requests that don't otherwise resolve. For example:

```java
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.AbstractResourceResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceResolverChain;

import java.util.List;

public class HtmlResourceResolver extends AbstractResourceResolver {
    private static final String HTML_SUFFIX = ".html";

    @Override
    protected Resource resolveResourceInternal(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath,
                                               List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
        Resource resolved = chain.resolveResource(request, requestPath, locations);
        return resolved == null ? chain.resolveResource(request, requestPath + HTML_SUFFIX, locations) : resolved;
    }

    @Override
    protected String resolveUrlPathInternal(String resourceUrlPath, List<? extends Resource> locations,
                                            ResourceResolverChain chain) {
        return chain.resolveUrlPath(resourceUrlPath, locations);
    }
}
```

Then you can add the resource resolver to your `WebMvcConfigurer` as follows:

```java
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/").resourceChain(true)
                    .addResolver(new HtmlResourceResolver());
            WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        }
    };
}
```